# .htaccess load different web app depending on route under HTTPS

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm working on a project made by a software engineer and by a team of non-technical people who know how to use Wordpress. That means that part of the platform is handmade, but still need to have Wordpress contents to be handled by non-software engineers.
My idea is to have two folders in my webserver root, one called /app/ containing the handmade code, and one called /wp/. So when the GitHub pipeline release new code into /app/ is sure not to touch stuff in /wp/ containing Wordpress.
I have achieved forcing the HTTPS with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

It works like a charm, users are successfully redirected if they use HTTP.
Now the problem is, I want to "reserve" the routes used by the handmade platform for myself, and in case the user is not calling any of those routes, then I pass the ball to Wordpress. I want it to appear as it is a single website, so I don't want the user to load the /app/appRoute or the /wp/wpRoute, I'd like to always load /route1, /route2, without specifying the subfolder into the URL.
The handmade platform should have priority, and it uses around 13 main routes (and some of them have subroutes), so I can hardcode them into the .htaccess file I guess. If the user is trying to load any of those routes, then I want to load the content into /app/route, if not, I'd load /wp/route. Of course Wordpress has its own .htaccess file, and the platform has its own, which is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

I'm very bad at working on .htaccess files and been searching around, it looks like I can't find the solution for my scenario.
Should I have a single .htaccess file in the webserver root deleting the Wordpress one?
Should I have two .htaccess, write the 13 routes first, and then eventually redirect to the WP .htaccess (is it even possible?)?
Do I risk to make the user face a "Too many redirects" error?

This hybrid solution confuses me a lot. Does anyone who has been in the same situation has suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is your "handmade code" using a front-controller pattern like WordPress?

Comment: Hi @MrWhite . The platform has an index.php file which loads different views depending on the route. Routes contain JS code that render different HTML upon API call. Thanks a lot.

Comment: So, do you have some mod_rewrite directives that route requests to `index.php` (your "handmade code"), in a similar way to how WP does it?

Comment: Yes @MrWhite, the web app .htaccess directives are shown in my second code snippet. As Wordpress it uses index.php as main controller. My confusion is about putting the web app under /app, Wordpress under /wp, and make all the routes look as they are a single thing.

Comment: How do you want to handle the static assets (CSS, JS, images, etc.) of both your "handmade code" and WordPress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the following requirements:

- `/app` subdirectory contains the "handmade code"
- `/wp` subdirectory contains the WordPress site.
- Neither `/app` or `/wp` should appear in the visible URL.

> Should I have a single `.htaccess` file in the webserver root deleting the Wordpress one?

You could, but I wouldn't. Keep the WordPress `.htaccess` file in the `/wp` subdirectory. Everything WordPress is in the `/wp` subdirectory.

I would use 3 `.htaccess` files:

- One in the document root. This manages the routing to either the "handmade code" in `/app` or `/wp` (WordPress). This should also manage the canonical redirects (ie. HTTP to HTTPS *and* www vs non-www)
- One in the `/app` subdirectory that manages the routing within your "handmade code".
- One in the `/wp` subdirectory that manages the routing within WordPress.

This allows you to keep the "handmade code" and WordPress entirely separate (in terms of development).

Your 3 `.htaccess` files would then look like this:

#### `/.htaccess`

```
# /.htaccess

RewriteEngine On

# HTTP to HTTPS redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Rewrite specific URLs to "/app" (handmade code)
RewriteRule ^app-route-1$ app/$0 [L]
RewriteRule ^app-route-2$ app/$0 [L]
etc.

# Rewrite everything else to WordPress
RewriteRule (.*) wp/$1 [L]
```

The "specific rewrites to `/app`" can be combined if there is a pattern. See below regarding static assets.

#### `/app/.htaccess`

```
# /app/.htaccess

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect any direct requests to "/app" back to the root
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=301,L]

# Front-controller
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

#### `/wp/.htaccess`

```
# /wp/.htaccess

# Redirect any direct requests to "/wp" back to the root
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Note the `RewriteBase` directives and slash prefix on the *substitution* strings are specifically excluded, to avoid having to specify `/app` or `/wp` in the `.htaccess` file itself. (Although this might mess with WordPress, that likes to (unnecessarily) use `RewriteBase` and will try to overwrite the WP code block.)

You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive, that already occurs later in the WP code block.

I don't know how you want to handle your static assets/resources (CSS, JS, images, etc.)? Currently, the above assumes that you will link directly to the assets within `/app`, ie. By including the `/app` path segment in the asset link. eg. `<image src="/app/assets/images/myimage.png">`. With WordPress you could link directly (ie. include `/wp` prefix) or omit `/wp`, since everything else is rewritten to `/wp` anyway.

Ideally, it would probably be preferable to omit both `/app` and `/wp` from your asset links, since you don't want to unnecessarily expose these to your users and it would otherwise make the sites dependent on these parent directories.

If your "handmade code" uses `/assets` for all the assets then you can rewrite these in the parent `.htaccess` file in the root, before your custom route rewrites:

```
# Rewrite "/app" assets
RewriteRule ^(assets)(?:/(.*)|$) app/$1/$2 [L]
```

This allows your "handmade code" to refer to assets using root-relative URLs, as if the app was installed in the document root.

Comment: Not only it was a working answer, but also beautifully explained. True difference between learning and copy & pasting. Thank you very much @MrWhite